# Restricting Binary Output to 8 bits or 4 bits

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

**Here is my FIRST Question**

Here is my code:

```
public class Bits{
   public static void main(String args[]){


   int i = 2 , j = 4;



   int allOnes = ~0;

   int left = allOnes << (j+1);

   System.out.println("Binary Equivalent at this stage: " +Integer.toBinaryString(left));

  }
}
```

The following is the output I'm getting:

```
Binary Equivalent at this stage: 11111111111111111111111111100000
```

How can I restrict it to only 8 bits from the right hand side. I mean `11100000` .

Please explain.

**Here is my SECOND Question:**

Also, I have one more Question which is totally different with the above one:

```
public static void main(String args[]){


   int i = 2 , j = 4;



   int allOnes = ~0; // will equal sequence of all 1s

   int left = allOnes << (j+1);

   System.out.println("Binary Equivalent at this stage: " +Integer.toBinaryString(left));

  }
}
```

Since I didn't understand the following line:

```
int allOnes = ~0; // will equal sequence of all 1s
```

When I tried to output the value of "allOnes" then I got "-1" as my output.

I'm having hard time understanding the very next line which is as follows:

```
int left = allOnes << (j+1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int allOnes = ~0;
```

Takes the integer 0 and applies the NOT operation bitwise so it will have all ones in its binary representation.  Intagers use the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) format, meaning that a value of a word having all bits as one is value of -1.

Answer (score 0):

8 bits in decimal has a maximum value of 255. You can use the modulo (remainder) division operator to limit it to 8 bits at this point. For isntance:

```
int yournum = 35928304284 % 256;
```

will limit `yournum` to 8 bits of length. Additionally, as suggested in the comments, you can do this:

```
int yournum = 3598249230 & 255;
```

This works as well, and is actually preferred in this case, because it is much faster. The bitwise and function returns 1 if both associated bits are 1; since only the last 8 bits of 255 are one, the integer is implicitly limited to 255.

To answer your second question: A tilde is the bitwise inversion operator. Thus,

```
int allOnes = ~0;
```

creates an integer of all 1s. Because of the way [twos complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works, that number actually represents -1.

Comment: You may find & works better than % here.  You do NOT want to go dividing by 255.

Comment: @DavidWallace Oh, yeah, forgot about that. Edited in, thanks!

Comment: @awashburn Right. That's what I get for writing this at 1AM, I suppose!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you only care about byte boundaries, then use a [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

   byte lastByte = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(i).array()[3];

To restrict this byte to the first four or last four bits, use `lastByte & 0b11110000` or `lastByte & 0b00001111`

1. The integer representation of -1 is all 1's, i.e. 32 bits all set to 1.  You can think of the first bit as -2^31 (note the negative sign), and of each subsequent bit as 2^30, 2^29, etc.  Adding 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 ... + 2^30 - 2^31 = -1.

I suggest reading [this tutorial on bitwise operations](http://vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html).

Answer (score 0):

For #1 Integer.toBinaryString(left) is printing 32 bits (length of Integer), so if you just want the right 8 you can do the following:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(left).substring(24)
```

The ~ operator in Java inverts the the bit pattern.  Thus 0 turns into ffff.

The  << operator shifts the bits by x.  You are shifting the bits to the left by 5 so you end up with 5 zeros on the right.

Here are all the [bitwise operators for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, a more general solution for the first question than what I've seen so far is

```
left &= (2 ^ n) - 1;
```

where n is the number of binary digits that you want to take from the right. This is based around the bitwise AND operator, &, which compares corresponding bits in two numbers and outputs a 1 if they are both 1s and 0 otherwise. For example:

```
10011001 & 11110000 == 10010000; // true
```

This is used to create what are known as bitmasks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)). Notice how in this example how the left 4 bits of the first number are copied over to the result and how those same 4 bits are all ones in the second number? That's the idea in a bit mask.

So in your case, let's look at n = 8

```
left &= (2 ^ 8) - 1;

left &= 256 - 1;

left &= 255; // Note that &=, like += or *=, just means left = left & 255
             // Also, 255 is 11111111 in binary so it can be used as the bitmask for
             // the 8 rightmost bits.

Integer.toBinaryString(left) = "11100000";
```

Your second question is much more in depth, but you'd probably benefit most from reading the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) instead of trying to understand a brief explanation here.